# Maven: credentials correct but getting Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized

Tags: maven

I verified that the setting.yml credentials is correct by using another device. When I try to run mvn clean install, I am getting cryptic error messages such as "Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized" on maven@3.5

When I switched to maven@3.8, I get "maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories" instead.

Anyone who came across similar issues?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is that coming from: `setting.yml`? First an unauthorized means your credentials are not correct or wrong configured... furthermore "maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories" is a hint that you are accessing repositories not with `https`...Information how to come around the `https` part see the release notes: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html

Comment: Hi, you are right that the repo is not under https. Weirdly, I was able to clean and build when I was on the old Intel chip Macbookpro but with the same setup (via time machine), I am having this problem on the new Apple Silicon Macbookpro

Comment: It not related to Mac M1 etc. it's related to your upgrade from Maven 3.5 to 3.8.X.. This is a combination of two things: Authorization and http vs. https...

Comment: managed to solve it by editing the settings.xml in the main maven folder instead of the ~/.m2/ folder. Thank you khmarbaise!

Comment: What do you mean by `main folder`? The user settings.xml should be in `$HOME/.m2/..`?

Comment: I installed maven via homebrew. The ~/.m2/.. file wasnt read. It was in Cellar/.. instead

Comment: The file in `$HOME/.m2/ is read by Maven by default ..you can check this via `mvn -X ... ` and checking the output within the first 100 lines there is an output ...`Reading ...settings.xml`... So you mistaken the system configuration which is located within the `conf` directory of the maven installation and the user configuration which is located in users home directory `~/.m2/settings.xml`...

Comment: I see. Thank you, I will try to re-configure to read from .m2/ again.